# Combing a list with multiple levels into a data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rstudio

I am pulling data from an API and my output is a list with multiple levels.

```
#data is the list received from the call.
str(data, 3)
List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ data:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 153
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ data:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 153
```

What I am trying to do is turn this list into a data frame. The code that follows is what I am trying to achieve, however it is various tedious and definitely not what I am looking for.

```
i = data[[1]][[1]][[1]]
j = data[[2]][[1]][[1]]
frame = as.data.frame(rbind(i,j))
head(frame)
ticker  tradeDate assetType priorCls
i   AAPL 2019-02-28         3   174.87
j   MSFT 2019-02-28         3   112.17
```

You will also notice that the rows are labeled "i", "j", I would like them to be labeled 1, 2.... Thanks in advance.

Replying to  Maurits Evers: Is this what you are looking for?

```
dput(data)
list(list(data = list(list(ticker = "AAPL", tradeDate = "2019-02-28", 
    assetType = 3L, priorCls = 174.87, pxAtmIv = 174.02, mktCap = 855332L, 
    cVolu = 140594L, cOi = 1838296L, pVolu = 91852L, pOi = 1350168L, 
    orFcst20d = 17.827, orIvFcst20d = 18.884, orFcstInf = 20.91, 
    orIvXern20d = 19.02, orIvXernInf = 20.2, iv200Ma = 23.06, 
    atmIvM1 = 18.04, atmFitIvM1 = 18.804, atmFcstIvM1 = 17.827, 
    dtExM1 = 16L, atmIvM2 = 23.155, atmFitIvM2 = 22.798, atmFcstIvM2 = 19.479, 
    dtExM2 = 79L, atmIvM3 = 21.539, atmFitIvM3 = 21.962, atmFcstIvM3 = 19.668, 
    dtExM3 = 114L, atmIvM4 = 22.147, atmFitIvM4 = 21.582, atmFcstIvM4 = 19.772, 
    dtExM4 = 142L, iRate5wk = 2.44, iRateLt = 2.52, px1kGam = 2304.59, 
    volOfVol = 0.0668, volOfIvol = 0.0456, slope = 2.427827, 
    slopeInf = 3.29858, slopeFcst = 2.44455, slopeFcstInf = 3.24424, 
    deriv = 0.0443, derivInf = 0.053, derivFcst = 0.0677, derivFcstInf = 0.0681, 
    mktWidthVol = 0.35, mktWidthVolInf = 0.372, cAddPrem = 0L, 
    pAddPrem = 0L, rip = 1.85202, ivEarnReturn = 0L, fcstR2 = 0.35, 
    fcstR2Imp = 0.32, hiHedge = 0L, loHedge = 0L, stkVolu = 27942952L, 
    avgOptVolu20d = 451784L, sector = "XLK Electronic Computer Manufacturing42941", 
    orHv1d = 12.79, orHv5d = 12.74, orHv10d = 12.68, orHv20d = 23.4, 
    orHv60d = 34.69, orHv90d = 36.12, orHv120d = 34.3, orHv252d = 28.34, 
    orHv500d = 24.48, orHv1000d = 24.54, clsHv5d = 9.12, clsHv10d = 7.96, 
    clsHv20d = 26.91, clsHv60d = 39.34, clsHv90d = 40.12, clsHv120d = 37.43, 
    clsHv252d = 30.35, clsHv500d = 25.56, clsHv1000d = 24.88, 
    iv20d = 18.82, iv30d = 18.51, iv60d = 20.68, iv90d = 22.61, 
    iv6m = 22.33, clsPx1w = 171.06, stkPxChng1wk = 1.73, clsPx1m = 154.0194, 
    stkPxChng1m = 12.99, clsPx6m = 223.2899, stkPxChng6m = -22.07, 
    clsPx1y = 175.4484, stkPxChng1y = -0.81, divFreq = 91L, divYield = 1.8, 
    divGrwth = 0L, divDate = "2019-05-08", divAmt = 0.79, nextErn = "0000-00-00", 
    nextErnTod = 1630L, lastErn = "2019-01-29", lastErnTod = 3L, 
    absAvgErnMv = 4.7381, impliedIee = 4L, daysToNextErn = 0L, 
    tkOver = 0L, etfIncl = "", bestEtf = "XLK", sectorName = "Technology Hardware & Equipment", 
    correlSpy1m = 0.97, correlSpy1y = 0.92, correlEtf1m = 0.97, 
    correlEtf1y = 0.95, beta1m = 0.95, beta1y = 1.71, ivPctile1m = 9L, 
    ivPctile1y = 33L, ivPctileSpy = 37L, ivPctileEtf = 59L, ivStdvMean = -0.39, 
    ivStdv1y = 5.48, ivSpyRatio = 1.63, ivSpyRatioAvg1m = 1.49, 
    ivSpyRatioAvg1y = 1.51, ivSpyRatioStdv1y = 5.05, ivEtfRatio = 1.25, 
    ivEtfRatioAvg1m = 1.14, ivEtfRatioAvg1y = 1.13, ivEtFratioStdv1y = 4.16, 
    ivHvXernRatio = 1.12, ivHvXernRatio1m = 0.82, ivHvXernRatio1y = 0.8, 
    ivHvXernRatioStdv1y = 2.1, etfIvHvXernRatio = 1.03, etfIvHvXernRatio1m = 0.94, 
    etfIvHvXernRatio1y = 1.01, etfIvHvXernRatioStdv1y = 0.06, 
    slopepctile = 29.37, slopeavg1m = 2.17, slopeavg1y = 2.81, 
    slopeStdv1y = 0.7, etfSlopeRatio = 0.32, etfSlopeRatioAvg1m = 0.3, 
    etfSlopeRatioAvg1y = 0.38, etfSlopeRatioAvgStdv1y = 0.1, 
    impliedR2 = 0.4696, contango = 0.00818152984720655, nextDiv = 0.79, 
    impliedNextDiv = 0.47798, annActDiv = 3.17374, annIdiv = 0.952153, 
    borrow30 = 2.28035189211369, borrow2yr = 1.64744015783072, 
    error = 0.00449377548648044, confidence = 92.8030908107758, 
    updatedAt = "2019-02-28 15:00:06"))), list(data = list(list(
    ticker = "MSFT", tradeDate = "2019-02-28", assetType = 3L, 
    priorCls = 112.17, pxAtmIv = 112.13, mktCap = 863378L, cVolu = 63737L, 
    cOi = 729653L, pVolu = 36709L, pOi = 657741L, orFcst20d = 17.765, 
    orIvFcst20d = 18.768, orFcstInf = 20.45, orIvXern20d = 18.87, 
    orIvXernInf = 20.05, iv200Ma = 21.85, atmIvM1 = 18.761, atmFitIvM1 = 18.543, 
    atmFcstIvM1 = 17.765, dtExM1 = 16L, atmIvM2 = 21.694, atmFitIvM2 = 21.287, 
    atmFcstIvM2 = 19.535, dtExM2 = 79L, atmIvM3 = 19.96, atmFitIvM3 = 20.837, 
    atmFcstIvM3 = 19.602, dtExM3 = 114L, atmIvM4 = 20.017, atmFitIvM4 = 20.639, 
    atmFcstIvM4 = 19.649, dtExM4 = 142L, iRate5wk = 2.44, iRateLt = 2.52, 
    px1kGam = 872.54, volOfVol = 0.0699, volOfIvol = 0.0501, 
    slope = 3.241947, slopeInf = 4.00082, slopeFcst = 3.83885, 
    slopeFcstInf = 4.27056, deriv = 0.0736, derivInf = 0.0719, 
    derivFcst = 0.0709, derivFcstInf = 0.0833, mktWidthVol = 0.609, 
    mktWidthVolInf = 0.338, cAddPrem = 0L, pAddPrem = 0L, rip = 1.23683, 
    ivEarnReturn = 0L, fcstR2 = 0.3431, fcstR2Imp = 0.2827, hiHedge = 0L, 
    loHedge = 0L, stkVolu = 27837946L, avgOptVolu20d = 149633.8, 
    sector = "XLK Prepackaged Software42936", orHv1d = 12.74, 
    orHv5d = 19.25, orHv10d = 16.32, orHv20d = 20.37, orHv60d = 32.59, 
    orHv90d = 34.45, orHv120d = 32.68, orHv252d = 28.56, orHv500d = 24.3, 
    orHv1000d = 23.86, clsHv5d = 12.38, clsHv10d = 12.61, clsHv20d = 21.48, 
    clsHv60d = 31.95, clsHv90d = 34.01, clsHv120d = 32.35, clsHv252d = 27.74, 
    clsHv500d = 23.44, clsHv1000d = 23.81, iv20d = 18.35, iv30d = 18.97, 
    iv60d = 20.1, iv90d = 21.11, iv6m = 20.62, clsPx1w = 109.41, 
    stkPxChng1wk = 2.49, clsPx1m = 102.5022, stkPxChng1m = 9.39, 
    clsPx6m = 110.9944, stkPxChng6m = 1.02, clsPx1y = 92.2135, 
    stkPxChng1y = 21.6, divFreq = 91L, divYield = 1.6, divGrwth = 0L, 
    divDate = "2019-05-16", divAmt = 0.46, nextErn = "0000-00-00", 
    nextErnTod = 1630L, lastErn = "2019-01-30", lastErnTod = 3L, 
    absAvgErnMv = 3.1854, impliedIee = 3.0533, daysToNextErn = 0L, 
    tkOver = 0L, etfIncl = "", bestEtf = "XLK", sectorName = "Software & Services", 
    correlSpy1m = 0.93, correlSpy1y = 0.96, correlEtf1m = 0.95, 
    correlEtf1y = 0.97, beta1m = 0.5, beta1y = 0.42, ivPctile1m = 18L, 
    ivPctile1y = 30L, ivPctileSpy = 31L, ivPctileEtf = 50L, ivStdvMean = -0.4, 
    ivStdv1y = 4.89, ivSpyRatio = 1.56, ivSpyRatioAvg1m = 1.42, 
    ivSpyRatioAvg1y = 1.44, ivSpyRatioStdv1y = 4.82, ivEtfRatio = 1.19, 
    ivEtfRatioAvg1m = 1.08, ivEtfRatioAvg1y = 1.08, ivEtFratioStdv1y = 3.98, 
    ivHvXernRatio = 1L, ivHvXernRatio1m = 0.82, ivHvXernRatio1y = 0.78, 
    ivHvXernRatioStdv1y = 1.9, etfIvHvXernRatio = 0.92, etfIvHvXernRatio1m = 0.93, 
    etfIvHvXernRatio1y = 0.92, etfIvHvXernRatioStdv1y = 0.06, 
    slopepctile = 78.57, slopeavg1m = 3.36, slopeavg1y = 2.65, 
    slopeStdv1y = 0.64, etfSlopeRatio = 0.47, etfSlopeRatioAvg1m = 0.46, 
    etfSlopeRatioAvg1y = 0.36, etfSlopeRatioAvgStdv1y = 0.09, 
    impliedR2 = 0.4359, contango = 0.28540981002152, nextDiv = 0.46, 
    impliedNextDiv = 0.231564, annActDiv = 1.84, annIdiv = 0.928459, 
    borrow30 = 2.23711058497429, borrow2yr = 1.93625316023827, 
    error = 0.00123339532365208, confidence = 95.1030135154724, 
    updatedAt = "2019-02-28 15:06:27"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(data, ~bind_cols(flatten(.x)))
## A tibble: 2 x 153
#  ticker tradeDate assetType priorCls pxAtmIv mktCap  cVolu    cOi pVolu    pOi
#  <chr>  <chr>         <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
#1 AAPL   2019-02-…         3     175.    174. 855332 140594 1.84e6 91852 1.35e6
#2 MSFT   2019-02-…         3     112.    112. 863378  63737 7.30e5 36709 6.58e5
## ... with 143 more variables: orFcst20d <dbl>, orIvFcst20d <dbl>,
##   orFcstInf <dbl>, orIvXern20d <dbl>, orIvXernInf <dbl>, iv200Ma <dbl>,
##   atmIvM1 <dbl>, atmFitIvM1 <dbl>, atmFcstIvM1 <dbl>, dtExM1 <int>,
##   atmIvM2 <dbl>, atmFitIvM2 <dbl>, atmFcstIvM2 <dbl>, dtExM2 <int>,
##   atmIvM3 <dbl>, atmFitIvM3 <dbl>, atmFcstIvM3 <dbl>, dtExM3 <int>,
##   atmIvM4 <dbl>, atmFitIvM4 <dbl>, atmFcstIvM4 <dbl>, dtExM4 <int>,
##   iRate5wk <dbl>, iRateLt <dbl>, px1kGam <dbl>, volOfVol <dbl>,
##   volOfIvol <dbl>, slope <dbl>, slopeInf <dbl>, slopeFcst <dbl>,
##   slopeFcstInf <dbl>, deriv <dbl>, derivInf <dbl>, derivFcst <dbl>,
##   derivFcstInf <dbl>, mktWidthVol <dbl>, mktWidthVolInf <dbl>,
##   cAddPrem <int>, pAddPrem <int>, rip <dbl>, ivEarnReturn <int>,
##   fcstR2 <dbl>, fcstR2Imp <dbl>, hiHedge <int>, loHedge <int>, stkVolu <int>,
##   avgOptVolu20d <dbl>, sector <chr>, orHv1d <dbl>, orHv5d <dbl>,
##   orHv10d <dbl>, orHv20d <dbl>, orHv60d <dbl>, orHv90d <dbl>, orHv120d <dbl>,
##   orHv252d <dbl>, orHv500d <dbl>, orHv1000d <dbl>, clsHv5d <dbl>,
##   clsHv10d <dbl>, clsHv20d <dbl>, clsHv60d <dbl>, clsHv90d <dbl>,
##   clsHv120d <dbl>, clsHv252d <dbl>, clsHv500d <dbl>, clsHv1000d <dbl>,
##   iv20d <dbl>, iv30d <dbl>, iv60d <dbl>, iv90d <dbl>, iv6m <dbl>,
##   clsPx1w <dbl>, stkPxChng1wk <dbl>, clsPx1m <dbl>, stkPxChng1m <dbl>,
##   clsPx6m <dbl>, stkPxChng6m <dbl>, clsPx1y <dbl>, stkPxChng1y <dbl>,
##   divFreq <int>, divYield <dbl>, divGrwth <int>, divDate <chr>, divAmt <dbl>,
##   nextErn <chr>, nextErnTod <int>, lastErn <chr>, lastErnTod <int>,
##   absAvgErnMv <dbl>, impliedIee <dbl>, daysToNextErn <int>, tkOver <int>,
##   etfIncl <chr>, bestEtf <chr>, sectorName <chr>, correlSpy1m <dbl>,
##   correlSpy1y <dbl>, correlEtf1m <dbl>, correlEtf1y <dbl>, …
```

This assumes that all nested `list`s have the same number of elements (i.e. 153 elements).